# Garbage Collection in c++ for unassigned objects

Tags: c++, garbage-collection

I'm still learning all the ins and outs of c++ and I have a specific question on how it handles garbage collection with respect to a specific task that I'm doing. I have some class, Vector2D that contains coordiantes for a vector as well as a set of mathematical properties one can do to a vector (dot products, rotating, scaling, etc.) Laid out below is an example header file giving the layout.

```
#ifndef VECTOR2D_H
#define VECTOR2D_H

class Vector2D{
private:
    double x, y;

public:    
    Vector2D(double var1, double var2, int coordinateType);
    Vector2D *  normalize();
    Vector2D *  rotate(double angle);
    Vector2D *  scale(double value);
};
```

Now, I created this class in a specific way to have a specific functionality. When i have a `Vector2D` object, say `vec`, I wanted to be able to operate on the object and get back a new object, not change the `vec` object. I also wanted the ability to chain commands. So that way I could do something like scale `vec` and then rotate it with the command `vec = vec.scale(5).rotate(45)`. Each of these methods simply returns a new `Vector2D` object rather than changing `vec`'s parameters for this reason.

My question comes with garbage collection for this. I just don't know how c++ handles this and how I should handle this. technically in the process of doing `vec.scale(5)` a new Vector2D object is created which I then do `.rotate(45)` on, but then never use again. What's more, I have no way of even accessing that newly created object because I never assigned it to anything. So my questions are this.

1) Do I have to worry about deleting these new objects or does c++ know to remove them on its own?

2) If I do have to delete it, how can I do so without referencing that object?

3) If (2) cannot be done but needs to be done, is my construction of the code a bad practice? Should I change it to not do what I've done?

Thanks!

Comment: If possible, you should return a `Vector2D`, not a `Vector2D*`.  Then you don't have to worry about it.  The newly created vectors will be destructed automatically.

Comment: The standard C++ language does not require implementations to have or support garbage collections; most don't.  This is why dynamic memory allocation is frowned upon in memory constrained system.  You could overload the `new` operator to perform garbage collection.

Comment: I suppose garbage collection was the wrong terminology. I'm coming at this from a Java perspective as that is my more comfortable language. And thanks for the tip piedar.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Would you suggest I follow the line of piedar and dasblinkinlight and simply return 'Vector2D' rather than 'Vector2D *' or would you suggest I remove this functionality altogether and make my code not have this chaining feature.

Comment: Those of us who don't program in C++ like Java, we use locally defined objects before using dynamically allocated objects.  A rule of thumb is to only use dynamic memory allocation when the quantity of items is only known during run-time or the object is too large to fit into local or global memory.  Also, besides garbage collection, dynamic allocation slows down most programs.  Local allocation usually involves changing the stack pointer register, a simple operation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++ does not have garbage collection. Whenever you create objects using `operator new` and `operator new[]`, you are responsible for deleting these objects with `delete` or `delete[]`, depending on how the object has been created.

C++ lets you use temporary objects that get destroyed once they go out of scope. This lets you implement the API that you are looking for: all you need to do is declare your member functions return type without a pointer, mark your functions `const`, and return objects instead of pointers:

```
class Vector2D {
private:
    double x, y;

public:    
    Vector2D(double var1, double var2, int coordinateType);
    Vector2D  normalize() const;
    Vector2D  rotate(double angle) const;
    Vector2D  scale(double value) const;
};
```

This way you could chain the calls the way that you describe:

```
vec = vec.scale(5).rotate(45);
```

This will create a temporary object for the return value of `scale(5)`, call `rotate(45)` on it, assign the result back to `vec`, and destroys the two temporary objects created in the process.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was under the impression that this process was slower than returning pointers because returning the full object requires transferring all the information of that object whereas the pointer is nothing but a small reference. My program is calculationally intensive so I'm also concerned with speed and performance.

Comment: @zephyr That is certainly true in theory. However, compilers are allowed to optimize this very aggressively (look up "return value optimization" for details) so in this case the optimizer can make it so that no copying is performed.

Comment: "C++ does not have garbage collection." That statement was true at one time, but smart pointers were added to the C++ spec many years ago. It's just a matter of using them.

Comment: @MrEricSir Garbage collection has a specific meaning, which does not overlap with the way smart pointers operate. Unlike the non-deterministic garbage collection schemes, smart pointers offer predictable deletion of the resource. I think it would be a disservice to the reader to mix smart pointers with garbage collection.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight A refcounted smart pointer is a simple form of garbage collection.  There's nothing in the definition of "garbage collection" that requires non-deterministic deallocation.

Answer (score 1):

In memory constrained systems (a.k.a. embedded systems), we use pre-allocated arrays of objects as a memory pool and allocate from the memory pool.

Dynamic Memory allocation is avoided because of fragmentation concerns.

Garbage Collections is frowned upon on safety critical or timing critical events.

Comment: That is certainly an idea which I've never come across before, but sounds like an interesting one. But to be honest, simply returning the object sounds simpler and less time consuming to fix. As far as I know now, I don't think I'm butting up against memory constraints just yet so I don't think fragmentation is going to be an issue for me. It may in the future, but for now I think it's fine. Especially since this Vector2D object is minimal in memory size.